# ejb-jar.xml Tags Documentation

Tags: java, ejb, ejb-3.0

I am looking to add an interceptor class to an EJB.
According to my understanding I need to add a few tags to my ejb-jar.xml file to intercept all incoming requests.
Is there any documentation out there that can give me a full list of different tags I can put in the ejb-jar.xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Java EE: XML Schemas for Java EE Deployment Descriptors](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/index.html) is the canonical resource, which lists XML schema for multiple Java EE versions.

See [ejb-jar_3_2.xsd](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_2.xsd) for specific schema of `ejb-jar.xml` used with Java EE 8.